# Javascript executes before getting result from a ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the following  code which displays session data.The problem am facing is even if the session has value and the ajax get that data the alert that I have put below the function call getValFromSession(qes) always shows null data.I think this is due to the asynchronous execution of ajax with in the javascript.So I put some extra code as shown in the function
getValFromSession(qid).How can I overcome this asynchronous issue?

```
var qes=$('#qsid_'+q).val();
var res=getValFromSession(qes);

alert(res);//always shows null value

$('#select_'+).val(parseInt(res));   


function getValFromSession(qid)
{
 return $.ajax({
       url  : site_url_js+"controller/getValFromSession",
       type : "POST",
       data : "qid="+qid,   
       cache: false,
       async:   false
}).responseText;
}

/*controller*/
function getValFromSession()
{
   echo $_SESSION['time'][$_REQUEST['qid']];
}
```

Comment: "qes" Does this variable has value; if "qes" is null then "res" will get null.  please check "qes" is getting value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var qes=$('#qsid_'+q).val();
var res=getValFromSession(qes);

function getValFromSession(qid)
{
   $.ajax({
       url  : site_url_js+"controller/getValFromSession",
       type : "POST",
       data : "qid="+qid,   
       cache: false,
       async:   false,
       success: function(data) {
            alert(data); // alert here in successHandler
            $('#select_'+).val(parseInt(data)); 
       }
   })
}

/*controller*/
function getValFromSession()
{
   echo $_SESSION['time'][$_REQUEST['qid']];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` provides you with a `success`, `error` and `complete` callback handlers. Populate your response text in those handlers because the way you have implemented is synchronous and would execute immediately instead of after the request completes.

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code into a function and call that function on success event of AJAX as below

```
---
---
return $.ajax({         
url  : site_url_js+"controller/getValFromSession",         
type : "POST",         
data : "qid="+qid,            
false,      
async:   false,
success: finalfunction
---
---


function finalfunction(res)
{
  alert(res);//always shows null value        
  $('#select_'+).val(parseInt(res)); 
}
```